# cordova camera access from remote website

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I made an app with cordova for android platform.
In the index.html, on device ready event, I load a page from an external website:

```
window.open('https://www.miosito.it/camera.php', '_self', 'location=no,clearcache=yes,toolbar=no');
```

In this page (camera.php) I would like to access to the device camera for take a photo, but navigator.camera is undefined.

The plugin is loaded correctly in the app, because on OnDeviceReady event in index.html of cordova main page, this object is present and works.

```
var app = {

    token: undefined,

    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
    // 'pause', 'resume', etc.
    onDeviceReady: function() {

        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(navigator));
        // here it works!!!
```

What I'm wrong?

Here the software version I use:

```
cordova: 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.3 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-fcm 2.1.2 "FCMPlugin"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-camera 1.1.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-media 5.0.2 "Media"
cordova-plugin-media-capture 3.0.2 "Capture"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
```

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is an external webpage outside the environment of your Cordova project you won't have Cordova plugins available once you load the external page. Basically your `window.open` command completely replaces your Cordova environment.

Comment: Maybe iFrame your external HTML page and request the Camera in index.html. Or use the inAppBrowser plugin to load the Camera.php page, although maybe you can't access Cordova APIs the way you need - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

Comment: Well like it says on the page - "The InAppBrowser window behaves like a standard web browser, and can't access Cordova APIs". Try an iFrame - you will need some bespoke JS - and see if you can get the iFrame to call functions in index.html  ( where you will have access to navigator.camera )